# PHP - Allowing access to a file according to a $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, apache, session-variables, data-protection

I'm running an Apache / PHP server on which I have a video file.

Is there any way I could allow access to this file, only if some `$_SESSION` variables have specific values ?

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. Have you written any code? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @SunSparc I made a simple, codeless post since my question didn't need any and was quite general...
Does StackExchange specifically ask more a more detailled question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all put the video in seprate folder 
add a .htaccess file to the folder with following code

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

this will prevent any direct access to the file from outside the server but as your php server enjoys local file permissions can link to it

now you can use like if statement to check if session is set or not and accordingly provide access like

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['some_var'] == 'some_particular_value'){
    // show video
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

First at all, you must avoid direct access to the video file. This can be made puting it on a folder containing an .htaccess file with "Deny from all".

Second, you write a php script with code to check $_SESSION, and if ok, access the file indirectly. This script can be used as src instead of natural link to the file.

To accessing the file indirectly, you can use header() to send mime type and then output file contents with readfile().

An alternative is to create a temporaly copy of the file, with a hash name, just for the user is accesing it.